# Rails 4 Strong parameters, permit parameters for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

My params hash has attributes for multiple models which are all part of a collection and records must be created and tied to each other. e.g.

```
Model Collection 
  has Physical Items
  has Logical Items (takes nested attributes for logical items)
  has Locations 
   etc...
```

So even though my params hash is being posted to Collection Controller, it looks like

```
 Parameters: {"collection"=>{"client_id"=>"1",...and other collection params,  "logical_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"logical_item"=>"", ... other logical items attributes.}}, "item_1"=>{"item_type_id"=>"1",...},"other_loose_param_1"=>"loose_param_value".. etc...,  "commit"=>"Save"}
```

All these attributes must be permitted as all the records must be created as a single transaction and must be tied to each other. How can I get through strong parameters?

Answer (score -1):

The following is the answer.

```
params.permit!
```

Comment: You should know that this defeats the purpose of params.permit to filter input from the web. Big security hole.

Comment: Good of you to post the solution you found but this is a BAD Idea.  This basically just disables the strong parameters feature and exposes all values in your database.